# Chamisha Veshiv'im Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred seventy-five?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avraham Avinu lived 175 years

Answer (score 1):

175 are the *dapim* of *Bava Basra*, the *maseches* with the most *dapim*.

Comment: ...in the Vilna pagination.